# Getting undefined variable when using Phalcon filter?

Tags: php, phalcon

I am unclear here! I got error `Notice: Undefined variable: filter` when running below code!

But when I remove declare `public $filter` line,It worked !!! Why ?

```
use Phalcon\Filter;

class Auth extends Component {   
    public $filter;//remove this line is working
    public function initialize() {
        $this->db = $this->getDI()->getShared("db");
        $this->login_db = $this->getDI()->getShared("login_db");
        $this->filter = new Filter();
    }
    public function auth($name) {
    $name = $this->filter->sanitize($name,"string");
    }

    }
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file and a bit more code where it is calling the class and post the whole error with line number and file etc

Comment: Looks like you are running `auth` before `initialize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a [simple test](https://gist.github.com/victorsmirnov/5276fa88b29293b4d2ce4af8606e3827) and reproduced the issue. Let me explain what happens here.

1. `auth($name)` is a constructor for the `Auth` class. Yes, this is [old constructor style](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php). This method is called when the object is created. `initialize()` is not called before the object is created and thus the code `$this->filter = new Filter();` is not called before `auth()` method.
2. If you comment out declaration `public $filter` and access the property in constructor then the magic `__get()` method is invoked from parent class `\Phalcon\Di\Injectable` and the property is taken [from DI container](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon%2Fdi%2Finjectable.zep#L119). This is why no errors are shown.
3. If you specify the property `public $filter` and create the object the constructor (`auth()` method) is called before `initialize()` method and thus property is only defined but not initialized. In this case you get the error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function sanitize() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/app/models/Auth.php on line 19

Let me know if you have any questions.